# How to set Flask server timezone to GMT

Tags: flask

We have our flask server up and running. However requirement has come up to set server timzone as GMT instead of UTC. I could not find anything related to timezone in flask documentation. Is this possible? I know it is possible in django.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can make use of the python  `datetime.now()` instead of the `datetime.utcnow()`, or you can create a function that will automatically do the timezone conversions on all date objects for you on the sever.

I hope that will help you

Comment: Used date time.now(pytz.timezone('Africa/Lagos')) and still logging my activities as UTC

Answer (score 2):

This is  another option in flask

```
from datetime import datetime

import pytz

UTC = pytz.utc

IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
  
datetime_ist = datetime.now(IST)
print(datetime_ist.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Sorry  I am new to Stackoverflow . I can,t understand format for stackoverflow